# How to access a variable o watch a change in SwiftUI UI testing?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I'm new at UI testing with SwiftUI and I just wondering:
How can I access a variable or watch for sheet appearance in the process?
E.g. After login, I want to check if it was successful or not and then assert that boolean (which indicates which login was successful or not) or after-login sheet appearance exists.

Code Example:

```
import XCTest
import SwiftUI
@testable import Formaloo

class when_the_user_types_username_and_password_and_press_login_button: XCTestCase {

  private var app: XCUIApplication!
  
  override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    
    self.app = XCUIApplication()
    self.app.launch()
  }
  
  func test_user_should_be_logged_in_with_correct_username_and_password() {
    
    let usernameTextField = app.textFields["usernameTextField"]
    let passwordTextField = app.secureTextFields["passwordTextField"]
    let loginButton = app.buttons["loginButton"]
    
    XCTAssert(usernameTextField.exists)
    XCTAssert(passwordTextField.exists)
    
    usernameTextField.tap()
    usernameTextField.typeText("*****")
    
    passwordTextField.tap()
    usernameTextField.typeText("*****")
    
    loginButton.tap()
    
    // I don't know how to check the login being successful here!
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know how to find things on the screen so you just need to identify “what, after hitting the login button with correct credentials proves to me I was logged in?”

A success message?
An entirely new screen? Is there a control that is unique to that screen?

Assert on one of those things you expect to exist using `exists`

An added note, there is no reason to assert the existence of your login fields after you’ve pulled the value from them; getting the value proves they’re there so the assertions are redundant.

Comment: Exactly, my problem is: How can I find out a variable changed or how can I find out if there's a sheet showing up in SwiftUI?

Comment: “A sheet showing up” can be asserted by looking for the existence of an element on it. 

I don’t think you can access the app’s variables, but I’ve also never dug into it. This would be a pretty unique feature if it exists.